# Datatables binding with c# SerializeObject Datatable

Tags: c#, datatables

I am using datatables.net in the front end and returning a c# SerializeObject DataTable. I can see from the debug WriteLine that there is data and a row name Name. So I am not sure why I am getting this error and why the table is not being displayed?

JS Error

```
dataTables.1.10.12.min.js:91 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

JS code

```
var table = $('#tblTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: 'Handlers/GetResult.ashx',
            dataSrc: 'data',
            data: {
                "StartDate": txtStartDate,
                "EndDate": txtEndDate,
                "CommitteeIds": selecteCommitteeIds,
                "RoleIds": selectedRoleIds
            },
            type: "POST"
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "order": [[0, "asc"]],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "title": "Name",
            "data": "Name",
            "name": "Name",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return data != null ? data : '';
            }
        }
        ],
        scrollY: "500",
        scroller: {
            loadingIndicator: true
        }
    });
```

c# IHttpHandler

```
    dt.Load(dr);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine(row["Name"]);
    }

    context.Response.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { dt = dt}));
```

Comment: why? why are you using data table instead Dapper + data class ? `class Whatever { public string Name {get;set;}}` ... `var list = connection.Query<Whatever>("SELECT Name FROM WhateverTable WHERE ...", new { parameter  =  1});` then serialize List

Comment: I was thinking that they both would be SerializeObject anyway

Comment: obviosuly with current code you are serializing `class Anonym { public  DataTable dt {get;set;}}` not `DataTable` class

Comment: I have it using a SqlDataReader that is Execute Store Procedure

Comment: you can do the same with Dapper `connection.Query<Whatever>("dbo.ProcThatReturnsWhatever", new { parameterGoesHere = 1 }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)`